# Missing Boost Libs

Tags: c++, boost

I did something pretty stupid. I'm on Ubuntu. I wanted to reinstall Boost because of some issues. I used apt-get autoremove/purge, but I noticed that there were still some Boost libs hanging around: date_time, filesystem, iostreams, and system. I manually deleted those libraries, then reinstalled Boost. Now there are broken links for all four of those libraries. For example, for libboost_system I have libboost_system.a and libboost_system.so. However, libboost_system.so is a link to libboost_system.so.1.58.0, which doesn't exist. I tried using apt-get to uninstall/reinstall those libs, but no luck so far. Anyone have any suggestions for getting those libraries back?

Comment: since this is OS specific, probably better to move question to http://askubuntu.com

Comment: Ouch thats rough. Can you remove all the symlinks that point to the old boost location? That would at least get you back to square 1.